# Roman Numerals equation 1

Tags: lateral-thinking

The following Roman numeral equation is of course incorrect.

Make the equation correct by moving **exactly one letter** anywhere. You must place that letter in the equation (cannot remove it). You can be creative.

Of course "not equal to" or > or < is not allowed.

[image]

Comment: Can I move rot13(Gur yrggref Q be Z sebz lbhe hfreanzr? be gur yrggre Z sebz "Znxr gur rdhngvba...)?

Comment: No I dont think that was my intention.

Comment: To clarify, you mean move a single character (L, I or M)  in the equation to a new location in the equation to make it valid.  Would moving an I adjacent to another I to make a V or X be valid?    Does the construction have to be valid?  i.e. IM for 999 is not a valid Roman Numeral. Do you permit it?

Comment: Any single letter needs to be moved. The lateral thinking is "V" in "M " is also a letter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very lateral:

> Move the 'v' within the M, then flip the equation. Allow Roman on one side, Arabic on the other with ^ as the exponent sign

Giving:

> [image]

Comment: Ah, This makes sense given the suspicious amount of space between the 'L' and the 'I'

Answer (score 13):

Again very lateral:

> Move the L, rotate and shrink it and stick it between the last two II's, making an M  leaving I = M - IM

Comment: Wow. Hats off to your creativity!

Answer (score 8):

I believe I've gotten it.

> Take the bottom of L (which is a sideways letter I) and put it on top of the last I on the right (leave it sideways). 
>  This creates: II = M - IIT 
>  'T' is not a roman numeral, just a line above an I 
>  A line atop a roman numeral designates that it is multiplied by 1000 
>  The equation thus becomes 2 = 1000 - 998, which is correct

Comment: This works, and I like the thinking.  However, I'll be disappointed if this is the correct answer as 998 is properly written CMXCVIII -- That is your solution doesn't conform to the rules of construction.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore The formatting might be another part of "lateral thinking". Just a guess.

Comment: Could be.   Good answer, anyways.

Answer (score 6):

How's This?

> [image]

I'll update when I think of a better answer

Comment: Sorry @Joseph. > or < is not what I had in mind

Comment: @DEEM no worries, I'll get there

Comment: Upvote for noticing the "letter" that can be moved.  Nice.

Comment: Indeed. I applaud the creativity

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution.

> Take the $M$ and split it up into four parts: one "|", one "\", one "/", and another "|".

Next,

> Take the "/" and the "\", and put them vertically end-to-end above the "$-$" to make an (admittedly shifted) $L$.

This makes

> $LI = LIII$ with two lines that we still need to use. Obviously, we throw them on the left side of the equation between the $L$ and the $I$ to get $LIII=LIII$

Comment: That's really stretching the meaning of "by moving exactly one letter"

Comment: I suppose. @ChrisCudmore he didn't specifically say if it could be broken up or not.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain the downvote? The solution is perfectly viable.