# Roman Numerals Equation 2

Tags: lateral-thinking

This is a follow up for

[Roman Numerals equation 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80091/roman-numerals-equation-1)

With your creativity and lateral thinking and any ways you can think of (except the restrictions below), make the following equation correct moving only one letter somewhere

[image]

No using not equal to or arrow signs

Comment: move one letter right?

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Possible answer

> Move the C (surrounding the minus sign on the right) over to the left, between the I and M as shown: 
>  [image] 
>  Then, we have 1cm = (XI-I)mm = 10mm, which is true!

Comment: The question asked for lateral thinking, not overlateral thinking... :P Very clever!

Answer (score 5):

Here's another answer.

> ! Move the I after the X to the right of the E. This gives you 
>   [image]
>   
>   or $1m = 10e2mm$. Put it another way, $1m = 10*10^2mm=1000mm$, which is correct.

Comment: That is very lateral thinking and clever